# How to when item is added to cart its also added to div on other page?

Tags: javascript, checkout

#Hi I've successfuly make add to cart funtion,and I now need to make checkout page that display product details.I think I you can help me with that!
i've built it and I think I should some more lines of code and it will remeber what is added to cart and display it in div after clicking buy button.

here's code that adds product to cart :

````
// cart
let cartIcon = document.querySelector("#cart-icon");
let cart = document.querySelector(".cart");
let closeCart = document.querySelector("#close-cart");
// Open Cart
cartIcon.onclick = () =>{
   cart.classList.add('active');
}
// Close Cart
closeCart.onclick = () =>{
   cart.classList.remove('active');
}
// -- Works perfectly --
// Cart Working JS
if (document.readyState == 'loading'){
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
}else{
   ready();
}

// Making Function
function ready(){
   // remove items from cart
   var removeCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-remove');
   console.log(removeCartButtons);
   for (var i = 0; i < removeCartButtons.length; i++){
       var button = removeCartButtons[i];
       button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
   }
   // Quantity Changes
   var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity');  
   for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i ++){
       var input = quantityInputs[i];
       input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
   }
   // Add to Cart
   var addCart = document.getElementsByClassName('add-cart');
   for (var i = 0; i < addCart.length; i++) {
       var button = addCart[i];
       button.addEventListener('click', addCartClicked);
   }
   // Buy Button Work
   document.querySelector('.btn-buy').addEventListener('click', buyButtonClicked);
}
// Initialize total variable to 0
let total = 0;

function removeCartItem(event) {
   var buttonClicked = event.target;
   buttonClicked.parentElement.remove();
   updatetotal();
   updateCartNotification();
 
 // Set total to 0 at the end of the function
 total = 0;
}

function buyButtonClicked() {
   const cartContent = document.querySelector('.cart-content');
   const items = cartContent.querySelectorAll('.cart-box');
 
   if (items.length === 0) {
     alert('Your cart is empty!');
   } else {
     alert("Let's continue to purchase!");
     window.location.href = 'http://localhost:4242';
   }
 
   while (cartContent.firstChild) {
     cartContent.removeChild(cartContent.firstChild);
   }
 
   // Clear cartProducts array
   cartProducts = [];
 
   // Set cartCount and cartTotal to zero
   cartCount = 0;
   var cartTotal = document.querySelector('.cart-total-price');
   cartTotal.innerHTML = '$0';
 
   // Update cart notification
   updateCartNotification();
 
 // Set total to 0 at the end of the function
 total = 0;
}

// update cart notification function
function updateCartNotification() {
   var cartContent = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')[0];
   var cartItemsCount = cartContent.getElementsByClassName('cart-box').length;
   var cartNotification = document.getElementById('cart-notification');
   cartNotification.innerText = cartItemsCount === 0 ? '0' : cartItemsCount;
}


// Quantity Changes
function quantityChanged(event) {
   var input = event.target;
   if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
       input.value = 1;
   }
   updatetotal();
}

// Add to Cart /GRESKA/ 
var cartProducts = []; // Array to store added products and their options

var cartCount = 0; // initialize cart count to zero

function addCartClicked(event) {
   var button = event.target;
   var productContainer = button.parentElement.parentElement;
   var title = productContainer.getElementsByClassName('product-title')[0].innerText;
   var price = productContainer.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerText;
   var productImg = productContainer.getElementsByClassName('product-img')[0].src;
   var licence = productContainer.getElementsByClassName('licence')[0].value;

   if (licence === "Select Licence") {
       alert('Please select a licence');
       return;
   }

   // Check if the product has already been added with the same option
   for (var i = 0; i < cartProducts.length; i++) {
       if (cartProducts[i].title === title && cartProducts[i].option === licence) {
           alert('You have already added this product to your cart with the same option.');
           return;
       }
   }

   // Add product to cartProducts array
   cartProducts.push({title: title, option: licence});

   addProductsToCart(title, price, productImg, licence);
   updatetotal();
}

// Add event listener to Buy button
const buyButton = document.getElementById('buy-btn');
buyButton.addEventListener('click', buyButtonClicked);


// Handle case when user clicks add to cart button multiple times
var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-cart');
for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
   addToCartButtons[i].addEventListener('click', addCartClicked);
}

function addProductsToCart(title, price, productImg, licence) {
   var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')[0];
   var cartItemsNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-product-title');

   // Check if the product already exists in the cart
   for (var i = 0; i < cartItemsNames.length; i++) {
     if (cartItemsNames[i].innerText === title) {
       alert('You have already added this product to your cart.');
       return;
     }
   }

   // Create the cart item element and add it to the cart
   var cartShopBox = document.createElement('div');
   cartShopBox.classList.add('cart-box');

   var cartBoxContent =
     `
     <img src="${productImg}" alt="" class="cart-img product-img">
     <div class="detail-box">
       <div class="cart-product-title">${title}</div>
       <div class="cart-price">${price}</div>
       <select class="licence">
         <option>${licence}</option>
       </select>
     </div>
     <!--Remove Items from cart-->
     <i class="bx bxs-trash-alt cart-remove"></i>  
     `;
   cartShopBox.innerHTML = cartBoxContent;
   cartItems.append(cartShopBox);
   cartShopBox
     .getElementsByClassName('cart-remove')[0]
     .addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);

   // Update the cart notification with the number of items in the cart
   var cartNotification = document.getElementById('cart-notification');
   var cartItemsCount = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-box').length;
   cartNotification.innerText = cartItemsCount === 0 ? '0' : cartItemsCount;

   // Update the total amount in the cart
   updatetotal();
}


// Remoev items
function updateCartNotification() {
   var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')[0];
   var cartItemsCount = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-box').length;
   var cartNotification = document.getElementById('cart-notification');
   
   if (cartItemsCount === 0) {
       cartNotification.innerText = '0';
   } else {
       cartNotification.innerText = cartItemsCount;
   }
}


// Handle case when user clicks add to cart button multiple times
    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-cart');
   for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
   addToCartButtons[i].addEventListener('click', addCartClicked);
   }

   // Notification

   // Update Total
   function updatetotal() {
   var cartContent = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')[0];
   var cartBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-box');
   var total = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < cartBoxes.length; i++){
       var cartBox = cartBoxes[i];
       var priceElement = cartBox.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0];
       var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''));
       total = total + price;
   }
   // If price Contain some Cents Value
   total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;

   document.getElementsByClassName('total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total;
   }
   ```
</body>
````

Comment: use localstorage to save data in browser